# Как проверить SQLite3 скрипт на правильность до его исполнения?

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

Как я могу проверить `sqlite3` скрипт в `Python` на правильность, чтоб его проверка не затронула существующие данные? Например, это должно вернуть ошибку:

```sql
CREATE TABLE contacts (
    contact_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name TEXT NOT NULL
    last_name TEXT NOT NULL -
    email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    phone TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

Comment: Начинаете транзакцию, выполняете sql-запрос. Если ошибка - отменяете транзакцию (данные при этом не пострадают). Если всё нормально - коммитите транзакцию.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я не знаю как SQLLite, а MySQL автоматически комитит транзакцию при изменении метаданных. Кроме того `COMMIT` может присутствовать в самом скрипте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть только один способ узнать о корректности скрипта - провести его и посмотреть на результат.

Если вы сомневаетесь в корректности скрипта, то перед его проведением нужно сделать резервную копию базы, а затем, при наличии ошибок, эту копию восстановить.

И да, все эти манипуляции должны происходить при монопольном доступе к БД